# Increase the number of sites for flag "off-topic->another site"

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, flagging

If a question must be flag as "off-topic" due to "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network", the only current possibility is "belongs on ai.meta.stackexchange.com". No possibility to redirect to "stack overflow", "computer science", etc . It is not allowed neither to flag it without say a related site.

I thing a possibility of "others" or, at least, add the most usuals stack exchanges sites should be add to the current option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good idea. We'll need to wait, though, until our site graduates — a site generally [doesn't become available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178463/295684) as a migration source (except to its own meta) or target until the beta label is removed.

Moderators can migrate questions to any site, but I would guess that most off-topic questions are not suitable for migration because they don't yet meet the standards of the most relevant site. Such questions should instead be closed here with a helpful comment about the other site and a suggestion to review that site's guidance before posting.

Comment: This is mostly correct, but not universally true - Writing.SE has an active migration path to English.SE. In general, though, you are correct in that beta sites do not usually get migration paths.

Comment: @Mithrandir Interesting! I've inserted a word to become strictly correct.

Comment: You guys both know more about this than I, but Ben N I fully support you, and thanks for taking the lead on this!